# Is there any way to simplify my work and increase my productivity with regular Xamarin for Android?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'll be blunt. I miss XAML. I also miss DataBinding and markup that actually makes sense and is consistent in the naming of its properties. When it uses camelCase, it sticks to it, unlike android markup, which just does some properties with a `_` in between words, and others without it. It's a nightmare to handle without autocompletion.

Or at least, is there any way to omit the `android:`namespace? Writing it for each argument is torture. I'd go with just `a:` but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to skip it entirely.

Are there any third-party tools to make this less troublesome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible while working with Xamarin. There are a few solutions when working with Android in AS but in XS or VS so far there's not another way to do it unless you define your views in code.